# how to convert nsdate to another format using nsdateformatter

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have date string in this format Feb 23, 2014 coming from web services, I want to convert it to this format 02-23-2014, I am trying a lot but all the time nsstring return me null value

```
NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[DateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];

// date formatter two

NSDate *dateVal = (NSDate *)bookDetail.classdate;
NSLog(@"date %@",dateVal);

NSString *dateTwo = [DateFormatter stringFromDate:dateVal];
NSLog(@"new date string %@",dateTwo);
```

Comment: Also, `*DateFormatter` should start with lower case, `*dateFormatter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *dateString = @"Feb 23, 2014";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```